Replace overlapping intervals with non-overlapping intervals in a dataframe
I need to clean up a dataframe by eliminating any overlapping intervals. The dataframe generally looks like this:
   start    end     speaker
0   0.03   0.33  SPEAKER_02
1   1.24   6.91  SPEAKER_02
2   1.38   2.03  SPEAKER_00
3   7.11   9.64  SPEAKER_02
4   9.80  21.02  SPEAKER_02
5  15.37  15.52  SPEAKER_01
6  16.55  16.80  SPEAKER_00
7  21.36  26.40  SPEAKER_02
8  26.76  27.01  SPEAKER_02

In the case that rows overlap, I would like simply to create new rows without any overlap.
The original rows 1 and 2 would turn into 3 rows with these non-overlapping intervals:
1   1.24   1.37  SPEAKER_02
2   1.38   2.03  SPEAKER_00
3   2.04   6.91  SPEAKER_02

The original rows 4, 5, and 6 would turn into 4 rows with these non-overlapping intervals:
4   9.80  15.36  SPEAKER_02
5  15.37  15.52  SPEAKER_01
6  15.53  16.54  SPEAKER_02
7  16.55  16.80  SPEAKER_00

So the output dataframe would turn into 10 rows of these non-overlapping intervals:
    start    end     speaker
 0   0.03   0.33  SPEAKER_02
 1   1.24   1.37  SPEAKER_02
 2   1.38   2.03  SPEAKER_00
 3   2.04   6.91  SPEAKER_02
 4   7.11   9.64  SPEAKER_02
 5   9.80  15.36  SPEAKER_02
 6  15.37  15.52  SPEAKER_01
 7  15.53  16.54  SPEAKER_02
 8  16.55  16.80  SPEAKER_00
 9  21.36  26.40  SPEAKER_02
10  26.76  27.01  SPEAKER_02

As always, the data are huge, and efficiency counts.
I've tried some built-in interval analysis, but keep falling-back to custom for loops because I ultimately need to alter the rows.

You could first identify the overlapping intervals, then split into disjoint intervals, finally perform a conditional_join (using janitor):
def to_intervals(x):
    vals = np.sort(x.values.ravel())
    return pd.DataFrame({'start': vals[:-1],
                         'end': vals[1:]-0.01*np.r_[np.ones(len(vals)-2), 0]
                        })

tmp = (df
   # identify the overlapping intervals
   .sort_values(by=['start', 'end'])
   .assign(max_end=lambda d: d['end'].cummax(),
           group=lambda d: d['start'].ge(d['max_end'].shift()).cumsum())
)

out = (tmp.groupby('group')[['start', 'end']].apply(to_intervals)
          .conditional_join(tmp,
                            ('start', 'start', '>='),
                            ('end', 'end', '<='),
                            how='left', keep='last',
                            right_columns=['speaker', 'group'],
                           )
      )

Output:
    start    end     speaker  group
0    0.03   0.33  SPEAKER_02      0
1    1.24   1.37  SPEAKER_02      1
2    1.38   2.02  SPEAKER_00      1
3    2.03   6.91  SPEAKER_02      1
4    7.11   9.64  SPEAKER_02      2
5    9.80  15.36  SPEAKER_02      3
6   15.37  15.51  SPEAKER_01      3
7   15.52  16.54  SPEAKER_02      3
8   16.55  16.79  SPEAKER_00      3
9   16.80  21.02  SPEAKER_02      3
10  21.36  26.40  SPEAKER_02      4
11  26.76  27.01  SPEAKER_02      5

Intermediate tmp:
   start    end     speaker  max_end  group
0   0.03   0.33  SPEAKER_02     0.33      0
1   1.24   6.91  SPEAKER_02     6.91      1
2   1.38   2.03  SPEAKER_00     6.91      1
3   7.11   9.64  SPEAKER_02     9.64      2
4   9.80  21.02  SPEAKER_02    21.02      3
5  15.37  15.52  SPEAKER_01    21.02      3
6  16.55  16.80  SPEAKER_00    21.02      3
7  21.36  26.40  SPEAKER_02    26.40      4
8  26.76  27.01  SPEAKER_02    27.01      5

Variant: getting overlapping speakers
The last part of the code changes to:
out = (tmp.groupby('group')[['start', 'end']].apply(to_intervals)
          .conditional_join(tmp,
                            ('start', 'start', '>='),
                            ('end', 'end', '<='),
                            how='left',
                            right_columns=['speaker', 'group'],
                           )
          .groupby(['start', 'end'], as_index=False)
          ['speaker'].agg(','.join)
      )

Output:
    start    end                speaker
0    0.03   0.33             SPEAKER_02
1    1.24   1.37             SPEAKER_02
2    1.38   2.02  SPEAKER_02,SPEAKER_00
3    2.03   6.91             SPEAKER_02
4    7.11   9.64             SPEAKER_02
5    9.80  15.36             SPEAKER_02
6   15.37  15.51  SPEAKER_02,SPEAKER_01
7   15.52  16.54             SPEAKER_02
8   16.55  16.79  SPEAKER_02,SPEAKER_00
9   16.80  21.02             SPEAKER_02
10  21.36  26.40             SPEAKER_02
11  26.76  27.01             SPEAKER_02

